# Increasing size of red LED block in Neopixel rainbow wave code?

Tags: led, neopixel

I have been using this code to run a rainbow wave on my Neopixel strip, but would like the section of red LEDs to be more prominent, as currently the blue and greens are in large sections, while the red section is only about 3 LEDs long.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

class Strip
{
public:
  uint8_t   effect;
  uint8_t   effects;
  uint16_t  effStep;
  unsigned long effStart;
  Adafruit_NeoPixel strip;
  Strip(uint16_t leds, uint8_t pin, uint8_t toteffects, uint16_t striptype) : strip(leds, pin, striptype) {
    effect = -1;
    effects = toteffects;
    Reset();
  }
  void Reset(){
    effStep = 0;
    effect = (effect + 1) % effects;
    effStart = millis();
  }
};

struct Loop
{
  uint8_t currentChild;
  uint8_t childs;
  bool timeBased;
  uint16_t cycles;
  uint16_t currentTime;
  Loop(uint8_t totchilds, bool timebased, uint16_t tottime) {currentTime=0;currentChild=0;childs=totchilds;timeBased=timebased;cycles=tottime;}
};

Strip strip_0(720, 9, 720, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
struct Loop strip0loop0(1, false, 1);

//[GLOBAL_VARIABLES]

void setup() {

  //Your setup here:

  strip_0.strip.begin();
}

void loop() {

  //Your code here:

  strips_loop();
}

void strips_loop() {
  if(strip0_loop0() & 0x01)
    strip_0.strip.show();
}

uint8_t strip0_loop0() {
  uint8_t ret = 0x00;
  switch(strip0loop0.currentChild) {
    case 0: 
           ret = strip0_loop0_eff0();break;
  }
  if(ret & 0x02) {
    ret &= 0xfd;
    if(strip0loop0.currentChild + 1 >= strip0loop0.childs) {
      strip0loop0.currentChild = 0;
      if(++strip0loop0.currentTime >= strip0loop0.cycles) {strip0loop0.currentTime = 0; ret |= 0x02;}
    }
    else {
      strip0loop0.currentChild++;
    }
  };
  return ret;
}

uint8_t strip0_loop0_eff0() {
    // Strip ID: 0 - Effect: Rainbow - LEDS: 500
    // Steps: 60 - Delay: 20
    // Colors: 3 (255.0.0, 0.255.0, 0.0.255)
    // Options: rainbowlen=100, toLeft=true, 
  if(millis() - strip_0.effStart < 20 * (strip_0.effStep)) return 0x00;
  float factor1, factor2;
  uint16_t ind;
  for(uint16_t j=0;j<720;j++) {
    ind = strip_0.effStep + j * 0.6;
    switch((int)((ind % 60) / 20)) {
      case 0: factor1 = 1.0 - ((float)(ind % 60 - 0 * 20) / 20);
              factor2 = (float)((int)(ind - 0) % 60) / 20;
              strip_0.strip.setPixelColor(j, 255 * factor1 + 0 * factor2, 0 * factor1 + 255 * factor2, 0 * factor1 + 0 * factor2);
              break;
      case 1: factor1 = 1.0 - ((float)(ind % 60 - 1 * 20) / 20);
              factor2 = (float)((int)(ind - 20) % 60) / 20;
              strip_0.strip.setPixelColor(j, 0 * factor1 + 0 * factor2, 255 * factor1 + 0 * factor2, 0 * factor1 + 255 * factor2);
              break;
      case 2: factor1 = 1.0 - ((float)(ind % 60 - 2 * 20) / 20);
              factor2 = (float)((int)(ind - 40) % 60) / 20;
              strip_0.strip.setPixelColor(j, 0 * factor1 + 255 * factor2, 0 * factor1 + 0 * factor2, 255 * factor1 + 0 * factor2);
              break;
    }
  }
  if(strip_0.effStep >= 60) {strip_0.Reset(); return 0x03; }
  else strip_0.effStep++;
  return 0x01;
}
```

Increasing the length of the animation overall does not improve this, as it increases all sizes linearly. Is there any tweaks I can make to the code to increase just the size of the red section of the animation?